# Can the instance of Git that's installed with Xcode 4 be used for web development?

Tags: macos, git, xcode4

I'm a web developer, mainly a front-end developer, and I've been using Git in my workflow for a while now and I'm hooked.

I'm about to get a new Macbook and my plan is to install Xcode 4 (to both use the iOS Simulator and dabble in Objective-C in my downtime). I know that Xcode 4 comes with Git, but I'm wondering if *that* particular instance of Git can be utilized for my web development projects, or is it possible that it can only be used for Xcode projects only.

Basically, with Xcode 4 installed, do I need to install Git *anyway* to use it with non-Xcode projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done the following:

1. Obtained the new Mac and booted into Lion for the first time
2. Downloaded Xcode from the App Store and installed it
3. Opened Terminal and typed `git --version` and "`git version 1.7.4.4`" was returned
4. CD'd to my Desktop and typed `git init` as a temporary test and "`Initialized empty Git repository in…`" was returned

(Now it's time to remove the .git directory on my fresh Desktop).

So, it looks like my question is answered: the version of Git that comes with Xcode—albeit not the *latest* version—appears to work file for *all* desired uses, even outside of Xcode.

Comment: You are right. Note that it does not prevent you to install another copy of git if you do want the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

You do. In fact, the Xcode interface to git is intentionally hobbled to be "feature-compatible" with SVN. They wanted a consistent interface, regardless of which versioning system was on the back-end. So no branching and merging. It does a `git add` when you create a file, in fact, so you don't even get to control staging.

I've quit on Xcode's git interface, I don't even let it know I'm managing its files with git via the command line.